# Make types optional when using RouteComponentProps - due to error: type...is missing the following properties from type '...': location, matchts(2739)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I have a component that I am passing the `history` object, with react-router. In order for typescript to accept the `history` prop I'm trying to use RouteComponentProps as follows:

```
interface FilterAccordianProps extends RouteComponentProps<any> {
}

export default function FilterAccordian({ history }: FilterAccordianProps) {
...}
```

```
<FilterAccordian 
  history={history}
></FilterAccordian>
```

This fixes the error I had from typescript about `history`, but now I get an error:
`Type ... history: History<...>; }' is missing the following properties from type 'FilterAccordianProps': location, match ts(2739)`

So it seems I need to make the `match` and `location` props optional. But I don't know how. Can anyone please help?

Comment: try this, `function FilterAccordian: React.FC<FilterAccordianProps> = ({history}) => {}`

Comment: Thanks! I've tried this and it removes all previous warnings, adding a new one: ```Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'FC<FilterAccordianProps>'.
  Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature '(props: PropsWithChildren<FilterAccordianProps>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null'.ts(2322)```

This is confusing since my return is wrapped in a <div></div> and contains a array.map() function to produce a list. Not sure why this doesn't work?

Comment: Changing it to ```export default function FilterAccordian({  history }): React.ReactElement<FilterAccordianProps> {``` seems to have done the trick?

Comment: What does the `FilterAccordian` returns ?

Comment: Just a list of toggles and inputs. It seems to be working now though so thanks for your invaluable help. You've saved me a lot of time! :-)